Why is the solution to $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^3-x}$ not zero?
The problem:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^3-x}$
How I was thinking of solving it:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^3-x} = \sqrt{0^3-0}=0$
My question:
Why does my math book say that the solution does not exist? How come it isn't zero?

Could it possibly be because $\lim_{x\to 0-}\sqrt{x^3-x}$ does not exist?

@Jasper has the right idea. To be explicit, try plugging $x = 1/10, 1/100$. Then, to deal with your $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ question, try plugging $x=-1/10$... In general one needs $$x^3- x = x(x-1)(x+1)$$ to be positive for one to be able to take its square root.

Assuming that you are dealing with the reals, the limit $\lim_{x\uparrow 0}\sqrt{x^3-x}$ exists, but the root is not defined for $x<0$.

@copper.hat still have an issue with your "not defined for ...$x<0$"...

@peterag Yep, unfortunately my 5 mins passed, so I will have to live in MSE hell for eternity where open intervals are written as $]0,1[$.

When $0<x<1,$ $x^3-x<0.$

The book likely has defined limits to require the function to be defined in an open interval surrounding $0$, except perhaps at $0$.

What exactly is the definition of $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ in the book?

I hate this kind of problems because it is very imprecise. And in fact the book is plain wrong, or at least extremely misleading.
So first of all, why the book says what it says? That's because if $0<x<1$ then $x^3-x<0$, meaning $\sqrt{x^3-x}$ is not well defined for those $x$. So what the book wanted to say is "you cannot approach zero from above".
But this is misleading because the question is about domain really, not about the limit. The limit does exist inside the function domain (which includes $[-1,0]$ interval) and is zero there. Which indeed you can evaluate by substitution, since we are dealing with a composition of continuous functions.
So the real problem here is: limits are not entities on their own, they need domain, some surrounding space, and functions are not formulas only. Once we use proper definitions, e.g. function actually is domain + range + formula, then the answer becomes really simple.

IIRC there are some beginning textbooks that define limits only at the interior points of the domain of a function. If that is how the book defined a limit, the book's answer in this question is correct in that context, isn't it? But it is still true that in another (arguably more standard) context, the correct answer is that the limit is defined. (See my comment under the question asking what the definition is, to which has not yet been a response.)


We should ask: what is the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x^3-x}$?

and since
$$x^3-x=x(x+1)(x-1)\ge 0 \implies -1\le x\le 0$$
as noticed in the comments
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{x^3-x}=0$$
while $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x^3-x}$ is meaningless.
Note also that, according to the more general definition of limit, when we take the limit we are implicitely excluding the case $x\to 0^+$ and in this case the result
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^3-x}=0$$
is perfectly fine.
Therefore the answer also depends upon to the definition you are referring to.
See also the related:

What is $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)}{\sin \left(\frac 1 x\right)}$ ? Does it exist?

